# How can I see angularjs ui-router resolved dependency object values using debug console without having to go through debug break point

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I understand that angularjs ui-router resolved dependencies are automatically inherited by child states. Also as child state is activated, the resolved dependencies of parent state is further re-evaluated and resolved based on currently "active" state.

I could set code break point to be able to see debug values of such resolved dependencies. However, I am wondering if it's possible to see them using debug console (say using Chrome dev tool's debug console).

For example, I can see currently active state's $state & $stateParams singleton object's values using following kind of debug command:

```
$("html").injector().get("$state")
$("html").injector().get("$stateParams")
```

How can I see "***inherited from ancestors***" resolved object's values using debug console?

Comment: When you get the `$state` object above, you can find what you're looking for if you dig deep enough. For example, in the `$state` object I'm looking at, I can find the resolves here:  `$state.$current.locals.resolve.$$promises`. Depending on your state hierarchy, you might have to look at the parent state (`$state.current.parent`) to find the resolves you're looking for.

Comment: Actually `$state.$current.locals.resolve.$$promises` does not show _actual resolved_ value. It just points to `promise' itself.

Comment: You can find it in the `$$promises` property once the promise is resolved under `$$promises.value` ... but your solution using globals is definitely better :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$state.$current.locals.globals` does provide details of actual resolved object.

So, to *quickly* see them for currently *active* state, following command in console window shows all the resolved dependencies (including inherited ones from ancestor states):

```
$("html").injector().get("$state").$current.locals.globals
```